# What is the equivalent of the 'HttpContext.Current.User.Identity' for a Windows application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, httpcontext

I believe HttpContext cannot be used for Windows application according to my research. 
I want to use an equivalent of HttpContext for my Windows application to implement something like this, for example:

```
Dim userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.Username` should do the trick for the currently logged in user, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will get the user for the application's thread.